# Celery beat cannot update currency exchange rates with django-money

Tags: python, django, celerybeat, currency-exchange-rates, django-money

I use [django-money](https://github.com/django-money/django-money), then I ran celery beat to update currency exchange rates every 60 minutes with the code below. *I followed [django-money doc](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#working-with-exchange-rates):

```py
# "core/celery.py"

import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

app = Celery('core')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

```py
# "core/tasks.py"

from celery import shared_task
from djmoney import settings
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

@shared_task
def update_rates(backend=settings.EXCHANGE_BACKEND, **kwargs):
    backend = import_string(backend)()
    backend.update_rates(**kwargs)
    print("Successfully updated")
```

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from celery.schedules import crontab

OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID = '5507ba2d9b8f4c46adca3169aef9c281' # Here

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update_rates': {
        'task': 'core.tasks.update_rates',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/60'),
        'kwargs': {}  # For custom arguments
    }
}
```

But, I got the error below even though I set `OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID` in `settings.py` as shown above:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> settings.OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID should be set to use
> OpenExchangeRatesBackend

So, how can I solve the error to update currency exchange rates every 60 minutes with celery beat?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID` to `update_rates` task with `'args'` in `settings.py` as shown below. *Actually, the celery beat example to update currency exchange rates in [django-money doc](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#working-with-exchange-rates) is old:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from celery.schedules import crontab

OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID = '5507ba2d9b8f4c46adca3169aef9c281' # Here

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update_rates': {
        'task': 'core.tasks.update_rates',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/60'),
        'args': [OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID],
    }
}
```

Then, `update_rates` task needs to receive `OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID` with `app_id`, then assign it to `access_key` in `tasks.py` as shown below, then you can solve the error, then update currency exchange rates every 60 minutes with celery beat. *You can see [openexchangerates.py](https://github.com/django-money/django-money/blob/main/djmoney/contrib/exchange/backends/openexchangerates.py) on GitHub to know why `OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID` needs to be assigned to `access_key`:

```py
# "core/tasks.py"

from celery import shared_task
from djmoney import settings
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

@shared_task     # Here
def update_rates(app_id):
    backend = import_string(settings.EXCHANGE_BACKEND)(
        access_key=app_id # Here
    )
    backend.update_rates()
    print("Successfully updated")
```

In addition, `OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID` can be defined after the celery beat code in `settings.py` as shown below without any errors and I recommend to import `crontab` just before the celery beat code as shown below so that no errors occur:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from celery.schedules import crontab # Here

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'update_rates': {
        'task': 'core.tasks.update_rates',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/60'),
        'args': [OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID],
    }
}

OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID = '5507ba2d9b8f4c46adca3169aef9c281' # Here
```

And, you can use the new celery beat code on `settings.py` as shown below. *`app` and `update_rates` task need to be imported from `core/celery.py` and `core/tasks.py` respectively as shown below and I recommend to import `crontab`, `app` and `update_rates` just before the new celery beat code as shown below so that no errors occur:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from celery.schedules import crontab # Here
from .celery import app # Here
from .tasks import update_rates # Here

@app.on_after_configure.connect # Here
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(minute='*/1'),
        update_rates.s(OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID), 
        name='update_rates'
    )

OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATES_APP_ID = '5507ba2d9b8f4c46adca3169aef9c281'
```